# threads en PyQt - TypeError: funcion() missing 2 required positional arguments:

Tags: python, python-3.x, hilos, pyqt5

Buenas tardes espero alguien puedo ayudarme con este error:
El codigo se ejecuta pero me lanza un error:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5 import uic
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db
import threading

class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("tabla-p.ui",self)



        self.funcion(self.tabla)

    def funcion(self,t):
        s = len(fire_val)
        while s >0:
            for key in fire_val.values():
                id = key.get('id')
                t.insertRow(t.rowCount())
                t.setItem(t.rowCount()-1,0,QTableWidgetItem(id))
                t.setItem(t.rowCount()-1,1,QTableWidgetItem(id))
            s =-1


    def fire():
        cred  =credentials.Certificate("2.json")
        firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred,{
            'databaseURL':'https://new1-3b819.firebaseio.com/'
        })

        ref = db.reference('/Productos_Bar')
        r1 = ref.get()

        global fire_val
        fire_val = r1
        return fire_val

thread = list()
thread2 = list()
t = threading.Thread(target=Principal.fire)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=Principal.funcion)
thread.append(t)
thread2.append(t2)
t.start()
t2.start()
t.join()
t2.join()

app = QApplication([])
p=Principal()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

este es el error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    TypeError: funcion() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 't'

    [Finished in 4.1s]
```

Comment: La instancia no la estás pasando a ninguno de los hilos. Los métodos `fire` y `funcion` los estás usando como métodos estáticos, pero no los tienes definidos como tal. Por lo demás, la variable global `fire_val` debería estar creada antes de lanzar los hilos si quieres que funcione. Desconozco pyqt como para ponerte un código corregido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo no entiendo como señala usted que funciona, porque ese codigo tiene muchas incoherencias, como por ejemplo:

- ¿donde has definido la variable `t` que usas como QTableWidget?,
- si `t` y `t2` van a ser threads, ¿por qué los creas como listas?
- la funcion fire se podria decir que es un método estático por ello no requiere de self y la descarga de datos es correcta, pero el método `funcion` no lo es, asi que ese codigo deberia lanzarte un error.

Ahora vayamos al problema de fondo:

- Qt y muchas otras librerías que sirven para crear GUIs no admiten la modificación directa de la GUI desde otro hilo, cada librería ofrece una metodología para hacerlo de forma indirecta, en el caso de Qt ofrece las señales que son *thread-safe*, para entender el motivo lee el [siguiente artículo](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread).
- Por otro lado personalmente evito usar variables globales ya que su depuracion es complicada, y peor aun cuando se usan junto a los threads. Otro problema es su abuso que se ve mucho en los principiantes.

Para la resolucion del problema voy a asumir que para el nombre del QTableWidget es `tableWidget`.

Voy a asumir que la data que se recibe tiene la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para enviar la informacion del otro hilo a la GUI voy a crear la señal `messageSignal`, y se va a emitir cuando tenga la data completa, esta señal se va a conectar a un slot que recibira y rellena el QTableWidget.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5 import uic

import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

import threading

cred  = credentials.Certificate("2.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, { 'databaseURL':'https://new1-3b819.firebaseio.com/'})


class Principal(QMainWindow):
    messageSignal = pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("tabla-p.ui",self)
        self.messageSignal.connect(self.actualizar_data)
        threading.Thread(target=self.obtener_data, args=("Productos_Bar", ), daemon=True).start()

    def obtener_data(self, endpoint):
        ref = db.reference(endpoint)
        fire_val = ref.get()
        self.messageSignal.emit(fire_val)

    @pyqtSlot(dict)
    def actualizar_data(self, message):
        for val in message.values():
            _id = val.get('id')
            count = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(count)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(count, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(_id)))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(count, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(_id)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = Principal()
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```